# Seagull Spread payoffs

Tags: options, spread, strategy, payoff

I'm looking at different option strategies and the ways that their payoffs differ (and therefore how they can differently be used).

I'm looking at the long seagull (buy a call spread and sell a put), and wondering if taking the opposite positions in these would provide an unlimited payoff with decreasing strike and a limited loss with increasing strike?

As an example:

- Buy a put with strike 1.2
- Sell a call with strike 1.3
- Buy a call with strike 1.4

Should the two calls not cancel once the strike hits 1.4 and therefore this is your maximum loss?
Whilst a strike 1.2 and below will result in a profit (ignoring premiums)?

Comment: To clarify, rather than unlimited payoff for a decreasing strike I should say an increasing payoff with decreasing strike. Obviously up to some sort of bound (not necessarily zero as EUR is in a negative rates world).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, at expiry, your gains on your put will be between 0 - 1.2 of your underlying; you will be flat between 1.2 - 1.3; you will lose between 1.3 - 1.4 due to your short call; and you will be flat > 1.4 of your underlying due to your long call offsetting your short call, ignoring premiums.

Answer (score -1):

Long put always has limited payoff (bounded by the strike)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23775)

Comment: @skoestlmeier this was not a criticism, i answered the first question. Why the downvote ?

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted, but i would like to encourage the downvoter to also add a comment on his decision here. However, i appreciate your contributions a lot, but as OP is a newcomer here, i suggest you to provide a more detailed answer with background information for clarification (like the accepted answer).

Comment: @skoestlmeier understood i’ll try to make an effort since OP made an effort himself to formulate his question clearly. Too many times new comers ask a very generic question and i recognize i don’t feel very eager to expand a lot in those situations. But thanks for your comment!